# C# labelling a variable as null to later return

Tags: c#

The code below is for an inventory class and what I am doing here is checking that an item (using the given id) is in the inventory class and returning it if it is. If it isn't I still need to return a null object of type item (another class I have created), however its still yelling at me saying that fetch doesn't always return something. Not sure if its my assignment of null or what??

```
public Item Fetch(string id)
{
    Item Empty = null;
    foreach (Item i in _items)
    {
        if (i.AreYou(id) == true)
            return i;
        else
            return Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Consider what happens if `_items` is empty. There's no return value in that scenario. You should be returning `Empty` *after* the loop instead.

```
public Item Fetch(string id)
{
    Item Empty = null;
    foreach (Item i in _items)
    {
        if (i.AreYou(id) == true)
            return i;
    }
    return Empty;  // We didn't find any matches
}
```

Alternatively, this whole method could simply be rewritten using LINQ as:

```
public Item Fetch(string id)
{
    return _items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.AreYou(id));
}
```

Comment: Bang on the money, specifically, the error in VS is because _items could be empty, then there is no return statement that would get executed at all.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you're getting the error is that your code will only execute on the first item in the `_items` collection. If it is empty, then it won't enter your `foreach`.

```
public Item Fetch(string id)
{
    foreach (Item i in _items)
    {
        if (i.AreYou(id) == true)
            return i;
    }

    return null;
}
```